# Create SQL Case statement to pull All warehouses from dropdown list in SSRS Report

Tags: sql, ssrs-2012

I have a sql statement in an SSRS report that is correctly pulling distinct warehouses from my dropdown list but, it won't pull any data when I select All Warehouses from my dropdown list. I would like to create a case statement within my query's where clause that would select All Warehouses after my shipper is selected.
[image: All Warehouses dropdown]

Query for the dataset

```
SELECT C.FDWLotNo, C.ShipperCode, C.Warehouse, Sum(T.TonsQty) AS Total
FROM dbo.tblInventoryTransactions2 T INNER JOIN dbo.tblCustomerInventory C ON T.CustInvID = C.CustInvID
WHERE C.FINISHED='False'
and C.CustID = @Shipper
and C.Warehouse = @Warehouse
GROUP BY C.ShipperCode
,C.FDWLotNo, C.Warehouse
ORDER BY C.ShipperCode
```

Comment: What is the value of "All Warehouses" in the drop down? Null? If its null `C.Warehouse = NULL` is not a valid statement. You may need to do `(C.Warehouse = @Warehouse OR @Warehouse IS NULL)`

Comment: for "All Warehouses" I want to show all warehouses where the shipper has inventory.

Comment: apc is asking what is the parameter value. Parameters have a value and label. The label is what is seen in the drop down but the value can be different (typically an ID of some kind). If both the label and value are both "All Warehouses" then use `and (C.Warehouse = @Warehouse OR @Warehouse = "All Warehouses")`